# Login using angular 7 and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, angular7

Need to `login` and `authenticate` user using `spring boot`, spring security and `angular 7`.

I have created an application in spring boot and angular 7.
I need to authenticate a user credentials and successfully login by the user in the system.How do I send the login credentials from angular to spring boot using spring security config.

Below is my SecurityConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/global/plugins/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
        auth

          .inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user")
          .password("{noop}password")
          .roles("USER");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show something which you have done?

Comment: Hello @Kevin Please share your code which you have tried

Comment: I have provided my configuration code. However I am unable to send the user details from angular ts to java.